# MFC Spin Control Buddy with Edit Control Error

Tags: c++, .net, mfc

I've created all my controls through the dlg resource. I've added code to control the spin control and it works perfectly. However, if I want to directly change the value of the edit box by typing a value into it, the program crashes with no error message other than "exited with return value 13."

```
void CNuanceGuiPart2Dlg::OnEnChangeSignalDb(){
// TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
// send this notification unless you override the CDialogEx::OnInitDialog()
// function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
// with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.
// TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

If I am to add any code into the above block that contains an UpdateData call or manipulates a CEdit/CSpinControl object, it gives me a debug assert at wincore2.cpp, Line 128.

EDIT:
So I figured out that the function is being called too soon when the code first runs. If I wrap the entire function that is being mapped from `ON_EN_CHANGE` with a `if(gui_start)`, with `gui_Start` signaling when `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` has been executed, any updates to the GUI can run fine - I don't even get a debug runtime error. My question is: anyway I can do this without the `gui_Start`? Why is the `ON_EN_CHANGE` for this particular edit box being called so soon? Does it have to do with the spin control? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well if you look up in the call stack in the debugger you'll see in your own code where it's breaking, so it should be easy to pinpoint.

Comment: Hmm maybe I'll have to do that. I'm not using spin control attached to an edit box for now... just a plain old edit control for now and it works fine. How strange. I'll update once I return to using the spin control.